# Angular2 displaying data from http get

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2.4 and I retrieve some data in a service using `http.get()`.

How do I display the data since this is an async method?

I was having problems using ngOnInit but it is displaying the data now. I tried the async pipe with ngFor but it did not display the data. When I navigate to another component to view the customer detail and then navigate back using `router.navigate` or `location.back()` or simply click a link or anchor tag the data was not displayed.

Turns out it was a typo in the template for another component.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: have you confirmed by add `console.log('ngOnInit fired')` to `ngOnInit`?

Comment: Hmm, it's firing but my code isn't getting executed and/or displayed.

Comment: and you can confirm whether your service is called by the same way i commented. BTW, confirm you have got data from your service or any errors.

Comment: It looks like my service is getting called but the data is being displayed in the template.

Comment: that's why I answered as using ngZone. have a try.

Comment: is your component have `implements OnInit`?

Comment: I tried using ngZone and it didn't work. It's weird that the service works when the page is first displayed or on page refresh but not when you navigate to it from code.

Comment: How to make the async call to `subscribe()` and then display that data once it is returned?

Comment: can you tell me that what are you doing in this line    `.map(this.extractData)` ? what is this.extractData is doing ?

Comment: Just try replace your code within the link and let me know If it prints customers..! http://kopy.io/WbiJl

Comment: Yes, it is getting the customer data.

Comment: @codecypher Is this some kind of parent component or? Or how is this related to the "other component" you navigate to and from? OnInit should be fired when you navigate to and from a component unless this is a parent component to other components.

Comment: I navigate to another component to display the customer detail and then navigate back. I have tried `router.navigate` and `location.back()` and just clicking a link `<a>` back to the customer list. None of them cause the data to be displayed. I have to click reload page on the browser for the data to display.

Comment: @codecypher So this is not a parent of the customer detail?